# SQL Server Full Text Search with complete sentences

Tags: sql, full-text-search, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure SQL database and tried the full text search.
Is is possible to search for a complete sentence?

E.g. query with LIKE-operator that works (but probably not fast as full text search):

```
SELECT Sentence
FROM Sentences
WHERE 'This is a whole sentence for example.' LIKE '%'+Sentence+'%'
```

Would return: "a whole sentence"

I need something like that with full text search:

```
SELECT Sentence
FROM Sentences
WHERE FREETEXT(WorkingExperience,'This is a whole sentence for example.')
```

This will return each hit on a word, but not on the complete sentence. 
E.g. would return: "a whole sentence" and "another sentence".

Is that possible or do I have to use the LIKE-operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
SELECT Sentence
FROM Sentences
WHERE FREETEXT(WorkingExperience,'"This is a whole sentence for example."')
```

If the above doesn't work you may need to construct the proper FTS search string using `AND` operator, like below:

```
SELECT Sentence
FROM Sentences
WHERE FREETEXT(WorkingExperience,'"This" AND "is" AND "a" AND "whole" 
                    AND "sentence" AND "for" AND "example."')
```

Also, for more precise matching I recommend using [CONTAINS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql) or [CONTAINSTABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/containstable-transact-sql):

```
SELECT Sentence
FROM Sentences
WHERE CONTAINS(WorkingExperience,'"This is a whole sentence for example."')
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your help!
The FREETEXT-version works like without the "..".
The CONTAINS-version would just return the entry which contains exactly "This is a whole sentence for example." and not with the LIKE-operator the entry with "a whole sentence"

Comment: @tschännie so does it meet your requirements or not? If you need exact results with "a whole sentence" only, then shorten the condition in the `CONTAINS` version to `CONTAINS(WorkingExperience,'"a whole sentence"')` or `CONTAINS(WorkingExperience,'"a" AND "whole" AND "sentence"')`.

Comment: no it doesn't meet my requirements..
I cannot shorten the condition. The sentence I have to search for depends on user input..

Comment: @tschännie but you said you wanted the whole sentence match, CONTAINS should do exactly that while FREETEXT does partial matches. Could you pls add sample data to your question and highlight what doesn't work in FREETEXT and `CONTAINS` with `"search sentence"`. Notice the internal quotes inside single quotes.

Comment: Ok I found a way that works for me. Although I don't think that it would help others, this is my solution: I try to remove any other words than adjectives and nouns.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is interested here is a link for a good article with examples:

https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2201634&seqNum=3

You can choose the best method to accommodate your need from the examples.

To me matching a whole sentence can be easily done with the below where clause as mentioned in the other answer:

```
WHERE CONTAINS(WorkingExperience,'"This is a whole sentence for example."')
```

if you need to look for all the words but user might input them in abnormal sequence I would suggest to use

```
WHERE CONTAINS(WorkingExperience, N'NEAR(This, whole, sentence, is, a, for, example)')
```

You can do other magics with this which can be found in the above article. If you need to order the result based on the hit score/rank you will need to use CONTAINSTABLE instead of CONTAINS.